# How to do assembly-time calculations?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

Result of

```
VarHeaderLen equ 2
VarHeaderSize equ VarHeaderLen * 8
```

is that VarHeaderSize is substituted by "2 * 8". How to make it to evaluate to 16 in assembly time?

Edit: I receive following error message from fasm:

> _gen_code.asm [225]:
>   mov rsi, qword [r13 + rcx * VarHeaderSize + VarValOffset]
>   processed: mov rsi,qword[r13+rcx*2*8+1*8]
>   error: invalid address.

Comment: That does get evaluated to 16 at assembly time. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Error message (see Edit)

Comment: @Jester: FASM `equ` is just a text substitution, which can be a problem for `len equ $ - msg`.  So you use `foo = bar * 8` for on-the-spot eval.  But yes, it does eventually become a compile-time constant of `2 * 8`.  Which of course doesn't work as a 2-bit scale factor in an addressing mode.

Comment: As Peter is telling you, we cannot multiply by an arbitrary constant for the scaling factor in the scaled-indexed addressing mode.  Only x1, x2, x4 and x8 are allowed: you're asking for x16.  See http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0110_scaled_indexed.htm . For that factor, you'll have to scale separately in its own instruction instead of using the addressing mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes: This question does not have answer on linked page. Answer is:    VarHeaderSize = VarHeaderLen * 8, "=" instead of "equ". Scale factor of 16 is another problem.

Comment: `rcx * 2 * 4` is valid FASM syntax isn't it? (with the `2*4` happening at assemble time, just not on-the-spot).  Yes, just tested with `mov eax, [rdi + rcx * 2 * 4]` and it assembles as expected.  So `equ` wasn't the real problem, and your title based on your guess of what the problem was unfortunately misleading.  `foo = bar * 8` wouldn't have answered the real question.

Comment: But if it makes you happy, there's a Q&A about FASM EQU vs. `=`